# iOS App with UIScrollView & TabBar creates whitespace after leaving fullscreen iAd or YouTube

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios-simulator, fullscreen, iad

Screenshots:

[Running in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc29E.png)
[After closing the iAd View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETSD2.png)

Problem Description:

After opening iAd or Youtube (in fullscreen), all the view elements behind are moved down 20 pixels or so.

However, even before that, all elements have to be moved down around 20 pixels in the XIB for them to render in the correct position without the white(gray)space.

Any idea why this is happening? I've tried editing the XIB and looking through the UIViewController subclasses, but nothing's worked so far.

Comment: Anyone? Nobody's had this problem?

Comment: I would imagine it has something to do with the status bar (which has a height of 20pts) disappearing/reappearing when going into full screen, and nudging your views down. Im not sure how your views are positioned, but Id look in the direction of the status bar as a possible source of the problem.